# inserting value of a particular xml tag into python tuple

Tags: python, xml

### Below is the xml file: Results.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Combinations>
    <Mode>PC</Mode>
    <Category>ADULT</Category>
    <Combination>
        <Parameter>
            <PEEP>1.0</PEEP>
            <Result>true</Result>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <CMV_FREQ>4.0</CMV_FREQ>
            <Result>false</Result>
        </Parameter>
    </Combination>
</Combination>
```

### Python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Results.xml')    
root = tree.getroot()

mode = root.find('Mode').text
category = root.find('Category').text
print mode, category

for combin in root.findall('Combination'):
    peep = rr = []
    for param in combin.getiterator('Parameter'):
    peep.append(((param.get('PEEP'), param.find('PEEP').text), param.find('Result').text))
    rr.append(((param.get('CMV_FREQ'), param.find('CMV_FREQ').text), param.find('Result').text))
    print peep, rr
```

### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AlAhAb65/workspace/python_code/prac1.py", line 59, in <module>
    rr.append(((param.get('CMV_FREQ'), param.find('CMV_FREQ').text), param.find('Result').text))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Basically I want to get value from xml tag to inside the variable like this:

```
peep = ((PEEP, 1.0), true)        # I want to check the tag before enter value and corresponding true will be insert into variable
rr   = ((CMV_FREQ, 4.0), false)
```

Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that inside the first tag  you do not have CMV_FREQ so it fails when you try to use it:

```
>>> for combin in root.findall('Combination'):
...    for param in  combin.getiterator('Parameter'):
...        param.get('CMV_FREQ').text
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

if you want to have what you have above you need to do:

```
  for combin in root.findall('Combination'):
    peep = []
    rr = []
    print 1
    for param in combin.getiterator('Parameter'):
      if param.find('PEEP') is not None: ##This will check if PEEP tag exists
         peep.append(((param.get('PEEP'), param.find('PEEP').text), param.find('Result').text))
      elif  param.find('CMV_FREQ') is not None:##This will check if CMV_FREQ tag exists
         rr.append(((param.get('CMV_FREQ'), param.find('CMV_FREQ').text), param.find('Result').text))
    print peep, rr
```

Another Issue 
peep = rr = []
makes peep == rr
so when you change rr, peep will also be updated
if you leave your code as it is the result should have been

```
[((None, '1.0'), 'true'), ((None, '4.0'), 'false')] [((None, '1.0'), 'true'), ((None, '4.0'), 'false')]
```

instead of:

```
[((None, '1.0'), 'true')] [((None, '4.0'), 'false')]
```